# Z- Index not working on menu

Tags: html, css

I am trying to implement a z-index on a menu sub-item show that it appears to be on top to the footer but i cant seem to get it to work. And im have trouble especially on mobile devices for menu items lower on the screen.

How can i solve this. Here is a [link](http://goo.gl/jqoanb) to the site

Comment: You should post some code or a JsFiddle instead of a link to your website or an other website that shows your website..

Comment: Please give a minimal example of the problem you have and tell what does not work as expected. Be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try  this

```
#ef-footer {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 1.1em;
    right: 0;
    /*z-index: 35;*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `z-index:0;` on the footer or just delete that `z-index`.

```
#ef-footer {
    position: fixed;
    z-index:0;       /* add this */
}
```